# Issues with IIS formatting and loading Resources in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm creating an ASP.NET Core MVC web application and I'm trying to launch it in IIS. Now when I launch it in visual studio it displays fine, but when I try to browse it in IIS I experience issues with the layout and with loading stylesheets.

Firstly, when I inspect the website to go into mobile view the dropdown button doesn't work. Also looking in the console I receive a lot of the following errors:

> Refused to load the stylesheet 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@300;400;700&display=swap' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

and

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-AFygw47OoEQWG93gLxfVt8/1l7fv/Jwf6Dagt3XHZs4='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present. Note also that 'style-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: You need to implement content security policy for that Google domain, or the error is expected. Read the linked thread and learn more.